# Query to Show only column names in impala

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala

In hive we can do "show columns in TABLE_NAME", to get only column name of  a table.But I want a query to show only column names of a table in IMPALA.How can i get only the column names of a table in IMPALA?

Comment: You can use `SHOW COLUMN STATS db.table_name` and then pipe bash commands with it to get only the column names (1st field in the output)

Answer (score 5):

you can use `describe db.tablename`

Answer (score -1):

```
print (cursor.description)
```

This line will print all column names.